# jquery events are not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two events that on placed on $('$gallery_slide_main_thumbs img') that are not being fired when I call them. Neither the hover nor the click functions are being called. the mouse pointer changes as it should when I hover over the image.

Jquery::

```
$('#gallery_slide_main_thumbs img').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: .66
    });
});

<div id="gallery_slide_main_thumbs"></div>

#gallery_slide_main_thumbs{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#gallery_slide_main_thumbs img{
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .66;
}

$('#gallery_slide_main_thumbs img').click(function(){
    $('#gallery_slide_main_thumbs img').eq(gallery_active_id).css({
        'border': '',
        'border-radius': '',
        'margin-bottom': ''
    });
});
```

The div with the id "gallery_slide_main_thumbs" is created on start up, and is populated with images when another function is called,

**EDIT:** The on.('click','img',function(){}) Does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically created elements by applying **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**:

```
$('#gallery_slide_main_thumbs').on('click','img',function() {
   $('#gallery_slide_main_thumbs img').eq(gallery_active_id).css({
       'border': '',
       'border-radius': '',
       'margin-bottom': ''
    });
});
```

for `.hover()` event, you can use:

```
$('#gallery_slide_main_thumbs').on('mouseenter', 'seconddiv', function( event ) {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
}).on('mouseleave', 'seconddiv', function( event ) {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: .66
    });
});
```

Comment: this causes the function to open the gallery that worked before not function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that images will be inserted dynamically in the following div:

```
<div id="gallery_slide_main_thumbs"></div>
```

So this means that images are not present in the initial markup and will be added into the div as a result of some other event.

In this case the **good old event binding just does not work**. So here another phenomena is involved that is called **Event Delegation**

Read more about this => https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

So the generic code in your case would be.

```
$(element).on('click',function(){});
$(element).on('hover',function(){});
```

I hope this works for you. Let me know if you need any more help regarding this.

Comment: using "$('#gallery_slide_main_thumbs img').on('hover',function(){});" and 'click' versions just prevent the function to created them in the first place to not work

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing partially with Talha Masood, but this event as a  complete code needs to be written on `document.ready` event or called as a function. So, probably something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(element).on('click',function(){});
    $(element).on('hover',function(){
    });
});
```

Let me know if everyone agrees here.